# Is ServerVector broken in OpenLayers 3.5?

Tags: openlayers

Is ServerVector broken in OpenLayers 3.5?

Just running the following gives an error:

```
var wfsTest = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

The error is: "Object doesn't support this action"

Am I doing something wrong??  It used to work fine in previous OpenLayers 3.x versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [change log](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/changelog/v3.5.0.md) of 3.5.0:

> The `ol.source.ServerVector` class has been removed. If you used it, for example as follows:
>
> ```
> var source = new ol.source.ServerVector({
>     format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
>     loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
>         var url = …;
>         $.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
>             source.addFeatures(source.readFeatures(response));
>         });
>     },
>     strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
>     projection: 'EPSG:3857'
> });
> ```
>
> you will need to change your code to:
>
> ```
> var source = new ol.source.Vector({
>     loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
>         var url = …;
>         $.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
>             var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
>             var features = format.readFeatures(response,
>             {featureProjection: projection});
>             source.addFeatures(features);
>         });
>     },
>     strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is still helping in 2020. Going through an OL 3 tutorial and to help me understand better I'm trying to also do them in OL 6