# Pgrouting "source not found error"

Tags: javascript, openlayers, pgrouting

Objective : To know shortest path between two points.

Background : Created sample data ,converted into table in PostgreSQL ,in addition created topology,routing using pg routing extension. Data is created in proper format

Now trying to  display data in OL3 but getting an error "source not found". Tried to check error on internet but not getting exact result.

For reference [used this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/#top) link

Software used : Tomcat 8.0 ,PostgreSQL 9.6/PostGIS, Pgrouting 2.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Please check attached screenshot for details
[image][image]
Code is available on [this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/#top) link

Comment: Can you tell, if PostgreSQL returns an error and which error it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you just download the code from app.js, it can only fails. The code is using deprecated API e.g `ServerVector` whereas the Boundless SDK is more up to date. See [this related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146489/is-servervector-broken-in-openlayers-3-5) to, at least, fix the issue for `ServerVector` in the JavaScript code.

Comment: I am solved that ServerVector problem.